# Wordress importing scripts

Tags: performance

I am fairly new to Wordpress theme development, and I'm trying to structure my code using the best practices possible
In your opinion whats the better option to import javascript files:

*OPTION 1*

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/anime.min.js"></script
```

*OPTION 2*

```
 wp_enqueue_script('some_script(s)');
```

in terms of loading time ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where in the page are you putting option 1? That's likely the only difference in load time, as option 2 will also generate a script tag but put it at the end of the page by default.

Comment: the option 1 was used in the footer.php

Comment: Then they should be equivalent. wp_enqueue_script will generate script tags where your footer.php calls wp_footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2. Option 1 is just flat out incorrect, not a valid alternative. The proper methods for loading CSS and JavaScript in WordPress are documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/). Also, there's no meaningful performance difference between the two.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Comment: wp_enqueue script is only loading the first script file is that normal ???

Comment: I'm using it like this `  wp_enqueue_script('script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/anime.min.js', false, '3.1.0');` for like 4 javascript files but only the first one is being loaded

Comment: Did you give them unique names? Please read the documentation I linked.

Comment: Yes fixed it after reading it ;)